# Basic C# query program

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How is it showing output 100 and 1000 instead of 10. Array a is assigned to new object o and then its assigned to new array b, how come array a's value getting reflected?

```
        int[] a = new int[3];

        a[1] = 10;

        Object o = a;

        int[] b = (int[])o;

        b[1] = 100;

        Console.WriteLine(a[1]);

        ((int[])o)[1] = 1000;

        Console.WriteLine(a[1]);
```

Output 100 and 1000.

Comment: Because `a[1]`, `b[1]`, and `((int[])o)[1]` all reference the same location in the array. You're not copying the array; you're copying a reference to the array.

Comment: Read up on how references work. As Enigmativity said, they reference the same memory location so you are changing the same location in memory.

Comment: Sorry i forgot basic stuff, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use new keyword you are creating new instance in memory

```
int[] a = new int[3];
```

When you assign value to the object, you are updating value inside the memory location you created previously

```
a[1] = 10;
```

In the below Step, you are pointing new variable to previously created memory location

```
Object o = a;
```

After this, if you update the variable o or a means you're updating the same memory location

if you want variable o and b to be different you have to create a new instance for variable o using the new keyword

```
        int[] a = new int[3];

        a[1] = 10;

        Object o = new int[3];

        int[] b = (int[])o;

        b[1] = 100;

        Console.WriteLine(a[1]);

        ((int[])o)[1] = 1000;

        Console.WriteLine(a[1]);
```